# Customize array from cURL XML response

Tags: php, xml, curl

I need to output an array with a specif format from a cURL request. I tried many ways to format the XML result as needed without luck.

Here's the PHP code

```
<?php
$request_url = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?nCdEmpresa=&sDsSenha=&sCepOrigem=71939360&sCepDestino=72151613&nVlPeso=1&nCdFormato=1&nVlComprimento=16&nVlAltura=5&nVlLargura=15&sCdMaoPropria=s&nVlValorDeclarado=200&sCdAvisoRecebimento=n&nCdServico=41106%2C40045&nVlDiametro=0&StrRetorno=xml 4110616,9034,000,001,50SN04004519,2014,000,002,00SS0";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 130);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);    

print_r($response);
?>
```

It prints the following XML

```
<servicos>
    <cservico>
        <codigo>41106</codigo>
        <valor>16,90</valor>
        <prazoentrega>3</prazoentrega>
        ...
        <erro>0</erro>
        <msgerro>
        </msgerro>
    </cservico>
    <cservico>
        <codigo>40045</codigo>
        <valor>19,20</valor>
        <prazoentrega>1</prazoentrega>
        ...
        <erro>0</erro>
        <msgerro>
        </msgerro>
    </cservico>
</servicos>
```

Or the following array if I apply `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [cServico] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Codigo] => 41106
                    [Valor] => 16,90
                    [PrazoEntrega] => 3
                    ...
                    [Erro] => 0
                    [MsgErro] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Codigo] => 40045
                    [Valor] => 19,20
                    [PrazoEntrega] => 1
                    ...
                    [Erro] => 0
                    [MsgErro] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What I need to return is and Array like this. I tried almost every method found in other questions here but never got a good way to construct this two-dimension array.

```
array(
    'Option Name' => array(
       'id'=>'40045',
       'quote'=>'20,20',
       'days'=>'1',
    ),
    'Option Name' => array(
       'id'=>'40215',
       'quote'=>'29,27',
       'days'=>'3',
    )
)
```

*Option Name will be retrieved afterwards by ID code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it. After testing all your suggestions and many others found on google, I came up with this:

```
<?php
$request_url = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?nCdEmpresa=&sDsSenha=&sCepOrigem=71939360&sCepDestino=72151613&nVlPeso=1&nCdFormato=1&nVlComprimento=16&nVlAltura=5&nVlLargura=15&sCdMaoPropria=s&nVlValorDeclarado=200&sCdAvisoRecebimento=n&nCdServico=41106%2C40045&nVlDiametro=0&StrRetorno=xml 4110616,9034,000,001,50SN04004519,2014,000,002,00SS0";

//Setup cURL Request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 130);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);  

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); 

$services = $xml->cServico;

$result = array();

foreach($services as $service) {
    $id = $service->Codigo->__toString();
    $quote = $service->Valor->__toString();
    $delivery_days = $service->PrazoEntrega->__toString();

    //Get simplified service name (option_name) 
    switch ($id) {
        case "40010":
        case "40096":
        case "40436":
        case "40444":
        case "40568":
        case "40606":
            $option_name = 'SEDEX'; break;
        case "81019":
        case "81868":
        case "81833":
        case "81850":
            $option_name = 'e-SEDEX'; break;
        case "41106":
        case "41068":
            $option_name = 'PAC'; break;
        case "40045":
        case "40126":
            $option_name = 'SEDEX a Cobrar'; break;
        case "40215":
            $option_name = 'SEDEX 10'; break;
        case "40290":
            $option_name = 'SEDEX Hoje'; break;
        case "81027":
            $option_name = 'e-SEDEX Prioritário'; break;
        case "81035":
            $option_name = 'e-SEDEX Express'; break;
    }


    $result[$option_name] = array('id' => $id, 'quote' => $quote, 'delivery_days' => $delivery_days);
}
?>
```

The final secret was to add `__toString()` to convert values returned as array to a simple string. It prints perfectly. Thank you guys!!

```
Array
(
    [PAC] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41106
            [quote] => 16,90
            [delivery_days] => 3
        )

    [SEDEX a Cobrar] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40045
            [quote] => 19,20
            [delivery_days] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work flawlessly!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);

$temp = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  foreach($v as $k1=>$v1) {
    $temp[$k][$k1] = $v1;
  }
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($temp);echo "</pre>";
```

http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/07/26/php-convert-xml-to-json-to-array-in-an-easy-way/

Comment: Sorry my dumbness, but it end up printing almost the same array as I posted. That is, I still don't know how to get to the desired results from there! :/

Comment: For me it seems like I need to perform a foreach loop on the 2nd dimension of the array (the one with [0], [1] as keys) to make them keys of the new final array, and yet access the data from the 3rd dimension to make them the array as value. I just don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: wait I will help you through.

Comment: run the modified code and let me know how much close we are! Note, i have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function (pass the response to it and it should return you your array) :

```
function getArrayFromResponse($response) {
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
  $array = array();
  foreach($xml->cServico as $node){
    $array[] = array(
       'id' => $node->Codigo,
       'quote' => $node->Valor,
       'days' => $node->PrazoEntrega
    );
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Comment: Did it. Replaced the `return $array`; with a `print_r($array)` and it almost nailed it. But instead of `[id]=>41106` as `key=>value` it printed `key=>array([0]=>value)`

Comment: I folowed what you posted, it souldn't happen ... anyway if that happend, just replace `'id' => $node->Codigo,`in my code with `'id' => $node->Codigo[0],` and it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 $sendurl = "http://example.com";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sendurl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 $response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $data);
 $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
 $array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($array);
```

Working charming for me.